# Trying to make bookstore application as a beginner

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I'm a beginner in JS and after i learned how to make Functions , Loops, IF , Arrays i found that there is a practice for what i learned that combines all these sections together to make a Book Store Library. i know how to do all those sections but individually i can't combine them to get the result i need. So i would like someone to help me understand how to create this Book Store
The requirements
1- Program can save a new book with [ID , Title, Author, Price, Quantity ]
2- Then we can lookup for a book using [ ID or Title Or Author ]
3- The Program should Check if there is quantity available for the book to be sold then decrease the quantity with the sold quantity.
So the book must be available , Quantity must be available and the customer balance is enough to buy the required quantity.

i Tried to initiate a function with 3 properties ID, Title, Author
then i declared a variable which contains an array with nested arrays of each type [ID, Title, Author, Price, Quantity]
but i dont know what if statement should be or how to lookup for a specific book using loop and if statement.

My Code is giving me undefined when i execute it:-

```
    function BookStore(ID, Title, Author) {
        
    
    let books = [
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      [
        "Start With Why",
        "But how do it know",
        "Clean Code",
        "Zero to one",
        "You dont know JS",
      ],[
        "Simon Sinek",
        "J. Clark Scott",
        "Robert Cecil Martin",
        "Peter Thiel",
        "Kyle Simpson"
      ],
      [80, 59.9, 50, 45, 39.9],
      [13, 22, 5, 12, 9],
    ];
    let bookId = books[0];
    let bookTitle = books[1];
    let bookAuthor = books[2];
    let bookPrice = books[3];
    let bookQuantity = books[4];
    if (bookId == ID.length) {
        for(let i = 0; i < bookId.length; i++){
            ID = bookid.length[i];
        }
        return ID;
    }
    }
    
    console.log(BookStore(2,"Start","Simon"));
```

Comment: You function returns nothing. What did you expect instead?

Comment: Uhhh you not return anything in that function

Comment: I tried return ID but it's not working as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a return statement? The reason your code is giving you undefined, Is because your not returning any information. Try using a return statement with the data you would like to log into your code.

Comment: Actually i don't know whether my IF statement and loop is written as it should be to lookup for the book with the ID atleast, when i return ID the function gives me undefined too

Comment: Question, Why not just log it to the console in side of the function?